# How to use SiteMinder as developer?

Tags: developer-tools, siteminder

I'm working on a large project using SiteMinder for access management.
Our team must develop web applications that consume web services, protected by SiteMinder.
To archieve this, our applications must "inject" SMESSION into the header of all web services requests.

That strategy works fine. However, we couldn't find a way to test web services calls from developers' workstation. Developers must develop and test web services clients without security (SiteMinder) and then deploy their code on an integrated environment in order to check that SM security is working fine.

- Is there a way to define a fake and permanent SM session on SiteMinder which will always be validated and that developers can use for development purposes or unit testing?
- If not, what is the best strategy to address this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a session from your development environment, ask your SM team for the credentials, location of login.fcc page and how to post to it.  When you form post credentials to this page, SiteMinder creates the session cookie and returns it to you.  Then you can use it for subsequent web service calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the Siteminder team to create a dummy realm which has a very long timeout (one month or so). Then login to that resource and get the SMSESSION cookie. You can keep injecting that cookie for your service calls for one month at least.